# Neo4j performance issue when saving, updating or deleting nodes using crud repositories via rest api

Tags: rest, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am creating a rest api with spring and Neo4j 2.0 as data store. 
The connection to the server is:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
         <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
</bean>
        
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
```

Queries are fast but the inserts , updates and deletes are very slow . The insertion code is as follows:

Domain model

```
@ NodeEntity
public class User extends Node {
    @ Indexed ( INDEXTYPE = IndexType.FULLTEXT , indexName = " user_name ") private String name ;
    @ Relatedto ( type = " knows" ) private Set <User> friends ;
    private String password;
    private String token;
    Profile private profile;
    private float affection;
    public User () {
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Service layer

```
user=new User ();
user.setName(name);
user.setPassword(password);
user.setToken();
profile=new Profile();
profile.setEmail(email);
user.setProfile(profile);
userRepository.save(user);
```

The log is as follows:

```
19:38:58,026 INFO AuditLogger : 16 - == > before create org.project.service.UserService
19:38:59,781 INFO AuditLogger : 21 - == > after create org.project.service.UserService
```

This is repeated with all kinds of insertions and deletions , especially with nodes with multiple relationships although these are not explicitly charged. A deletion sometimes takes several seconds. Queries are fast as expected.

The same operations using embedded database are very fast

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing. 
I did not pay for a license (maybe the rest api is just slower because they want it slower ...)
Indeed, with the embedded database it's very fast because you get a real connection and you do not use it through HTTP protocol ...

So, you are not alone in this situation maybe you can ask them directly about the rest api performance ... And it can be nice if they could implement a batch solution ...

Good luck !